# Generating XML by using XSD class

Tags: c#, linq, class, serialization, xsd

I want to generate an xml by  using a generated c# class from xsd
I made a linq query that save the query result in a var ReportData and I should use my c# generated class to save this data.but when I do var data = new FlashListFlash { ECUtype = modelType }; after the query the data is empty. can anybody help me how to fix this?

this is what I have done

```
string modelType = null;

LinqSqlDataContext db = new LinqSqlDataContext();
var reportData = from Vin in db.Vin_Ecus
                 from Global in db.Info_Globals
                              .Where(w =>
                                     w.NHard == Vin.NHard &&
                                     w.NVerHard == Vin.NVerHard &&
                                     w.NVerSoft == Vin.NVerSoft)
                              join Associate in db.InfoProg_wiTECH_Associas
                              on Global.NomeFile equals Associate.KeyJoined
                              where Vin.Vin == vinValue 
                  select new { modelType = Associate.Model_Type };


                  var data = new FlashListFlash { ECUtype = modelType };
                  //THIS IS MY Vin value probelm
                  //var data = new FlashList { Vin = vinValue}?????????????????????
                  var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(FlashListFlash));
                  using (var stream = new StreamWriter("D:\\test.xml"))
                  serializer.Serialize(stream, data);
```

this is my c# generated class from the .xsd file

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;


/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.1")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="", IsNullable=false)]
public partial class FlashList {

    private FlashListFlash flashField;

    private string vinField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public FlashListFlash flash {
        get {
            return this.flashField;
        }
        set {
            this.flashField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string Vin {
        get {
            return this.vinField;
        }
        set {
            this.vinField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.1")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
public partial class FlashListFlash {

    private string eCUtypeField;

    private string valueField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string ECUtype {
        get {
            return this.eCUtypeField;
        }
        set {
            this.eCUtypeField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute()]
    public string Value {
        get {
            return this.valueField;
        }
        set {
            this.valueField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my XSD file

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="FlashList">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="flash">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:simpleContent>
              <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="ECUtype"/>
              </xs:extension>
            </xs:simpleContent>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="Vin"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

The modeltype assignment is using the local variable which is null:

```
string modelType = null;
....
var data = new FlashListFlash { ECUtype = modelType };
```

You should assign the link query result:

```
var data = new FlashListFlash { ECUtype = reportData.modelType };
```

The vin value (vinValue) is not defined...so don't know how the code can compile, unless you did not paste all the code here.

Comment: it is defined but not pasted here. my code compiles but my xml file is empty. I tried var data = new FlashListFlash { ECUtype = reportData.modelType }; but modeltype is not a property of the reportData so it's red :/ 
just to clarify more my question: In my generated c# class I have to class one main FlashList and one subclass FlashListFlash that I should give value to them. and then serialize and save the result in one xml file
in FlashList there is the Vin fiels that is only one string and there is FlashListFlash whch I should give a set of value that is already in reportData